# How do I validate a selected value in a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I want the user to make a valid selection in a `DropDownList`, but I don't want to present any selection as the default so the default selected value is `-- Select --`.  I am using a `RegularExpressionValidator` to only accept selected values that contain a literal comma (since the valid items are formatted `LastName, FirstName`).

However, I am perplexed as to how to get the validator to look for the Selected value!  I'd really rather NOT make this a server-level validation, and if possible I'd like to keep it as simple as a Regex Validator.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddNames" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexValidator" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="ddNames" ValidationExpression=".*\,.*" 
    ErrorMessage="Select a Valid User">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The dropdown values are:

```
-- Select --
Smith, John B
Jones, Bill
Wilkinson, Harmony
Hull, Cordell
Hill, Faith
```

Is there a way to aim the validator at the SelectedValue?  As shown, the Validator seems not to be seeing any of the values in the control.

Comment: Can you invoke the validator when the form is submitted?

Comment: have you tried using `<asp:CustomValidator>`

Comment: Or maybe, when the user submits it (via button?) you could get selected item, then set the selected item. For controls, that sets off events usually.

Comment: @MethodMan, If this question cannot be answered as stated (with a RegexValidator aimed at the SelectedValue) then I might end up going with a CustomValidator that uses JavaScript.

Comment: @sln I know how to do that, but for reasons that I am not stating in the question (lack of space and relevance), I cannot in this instance use server validation.

Answer (score 4):

Am I right that you want to force the user to make a selection, and that selection should fit into your `regex`?
If so, you can easily add the [`RequiredFiledValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) class to your `dropdown` control, provide the [`InitialValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) property to it equal to your `-- Select --` item value so user will be forced to select something not equal to the `-- Select --`, and this value will be validated via [`RegularExpressionValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) control.

From MSDN:

> Validation fails only if the value of the associated input control matches this `InitialValue` upon losing focus.
> **The strings in both the `InitialValue` property and the input control are trimmed to remove extra spaces before and after the string before validation is performed.**
>
> Validation succeeds if the input control is empty. If a value is required for the associated input control, use a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) control in addition to the [`RegularExpressionValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) control.

Also you should note for a [`RegularExpressionValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) class, that

> **Both server-side and client-side validation are performed** unless the browser does not support client-side validation or client-side validation is explicitly disabled (by setting the `EnableClientScript` property to false).

So your code should be something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddNames" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexValidator" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="ddNames" ValidationExpression=".*\,.*" 
    ErrorMessage="Select a Valid User" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
  ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="ddNames" 
InitialValue="-- Select --" />
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Regex Validator does not appear to work to validate the SelectedValue of a DropDownList control.  My question is intended to smoke out a possible way to do so, if it exists.  I would have expected such an answer to have appeared by now, if one exists.  Thanks for your well-thought-out answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use RequiredFieldValidator.

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNames" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
 ErrorMessage="Please select" ControlToValidate="ddNames" 
InitialValue="-- Select --"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: This does work, and is the way I finally chose to do it.  I'd still like to know how to use a RegularExpressionValidator to do the job, but, oh, well.

Comment: RegularExpressionValidator will be used to validate some pattern.

Comment: Yes, I know this.  My question should make this clear.  But the RegularExpressionValidator does not seem to be able to pattern-match against the Selected Value of the DropDownList.  My question is intended to see if someone has found a way to make a Regex validator validate that selected value.

Comment: Just a thought could you pass the selectedvalue to a hidden textbox and then regex validate the textbox value?